# Джанго, добавление строки в значение класса модели

Tags: django

У меня есть простая модель:

```
class rumn(models.Model):
    ns = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    gs = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    ds = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

С помощью простейшего кода я создаю запись модели, сохраняю запись методом save(), проверяю:

```
>>> q = rumn.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> q.ns
'год'
>>> q.gs
'г'
>>> q.ds
'году'
```

Проблема заключается в том, что полю "gs" должно быть присвоено по очереди два значения: "года" и "г", но второе значение стирает первое.

Как сделать так, чтобы строки добавлялись к значениям полей, а не переписывали это значение?

Судя по всему, я могу создать список ["года", "г"] и добавить его в "gs", но наверняка должен быть более простой способ решить проблему.

Comment: Jsonfield использовать (если не sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

Советую для хранения небольших фраз в Django использовать **CharField** - это сохраняет память. 
Вашу проблему решит код ниже:

```
q = rumn.objects.get(pk=1) # получаем значение отдельной записи
q.gs = q.gs + "text" # Изменяем значение, добавляя к уже существующим данным строку "text"
q.save() # Сохраняем полученный результат
```

Обычное действие: сложение строк. Работает для строковых типов данных в Python (а значит и в Django)